# AlertDialog title loses top margin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-alertdialog

I am facing a really weird problem. I am using a custom `AlertDialog` that contains a `ListView`. I am setting the title for the Dialog and as long as the `ListView` only contains as many items so that they all fit on the screen, everything is fine.

As soon as the `ListViews` item count exceeds whats possible to display on one screen, the `ListView` (of course) gets scrollable. The second thing that happens is that **my AlertDialog title suddenly loses it's top-margin** (of approximately 10-15dp) that is usually present. Here a screenshot:

[image][image]

This is the code I am using to create the Dialog:

```
public class HighscoreDetailDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        Bundle b = getArguments();

        ArrayList<ResultInfo> list = new ArrayList<ResultInfo>();
            // fill the list ...            

        ((ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv1)).setAdapter(adapter);

        builder.setTitle("Result details");
        builer.setView(v);

        builder.setPositiveButton(getString(android.R.string.ok), new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  }
        });

        final AlertDialog d = builder.create();

        return d;
    }
}
```

How can I avoid this problem so that **the title keeps its default margin**?

Comment: Code would be helpful...

Comment: Allright here you go.

Comment: I struggled for another 2 hours and could not find a solution so I finally ended up removing the title.